# How to read NetCDF "global attribute" in C++

Tags: c++, netcdf

This is my first question:

I am trying to read "global attributes" from a NetCDF file (using the C++ legacy API). By "global attribute" I mean an attribute that was added to a NcFile, not to a NcVar.

For most things the "[Example netCDF programs](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/)" are useful -- but there is no example for "global attributes".

Consulting the "netcdfcpp.h" I find a few things:

- NcFile has a member function: `NcAtt* get_att(NcToken) const;`
- NcAtt has NO public constructor
- NcAtt is friends with NcFile: `friend class NcFile;`
- NcAtt has a private constructor: `NcAtt( NcFile*, NcToken);`
- NcAtt has a public member function `NcValues* values( void ) const;`
- NcValues has an API defined through the `ncvalues.h` header

My coding skills are insufficient to understand how I get back at the string/int/float stored as NcValue, in an NcAtt class within NcFile.

Attached is a example code of my problem "NetCDF_test.cpp", with the critical part missing from the implementation of the "LoadNetCDF" function.

The code compiles OK with: (edit: also, "TestFile.nc" is created correctly)

`g++ -c NetCDF_test.cpp -o NetCDF_test.o`

`g++ -o NCTEST NetCDF_test.o -lnetcdf_c++ -lnetcdf`

Example code:

```
#include <iostream> // provides screen output (i.e. std::cout<<)
#include <netcdfcpp.h>

struct MyStructure {
    std::string MyString;
    int MyInt;
    float MyFloat;

    MyStructure();      // default constructor
    int SaveNetCDF(std::string);  // Save the struct content to "global attributes" in NetCDF
    int LoadNetCDF(std::string);  // Load the struct content from "global attributes" in NetCDF

};

MyStructure::MyStructure(void)
{
    MyString = "TestString";
    MyInt = 123;
    MyFloat = 1.23;
}

int MyStructure::SaveNetCDF(std::string OUTPUT_FILENAME)
{
    NcError err(NcError::silent_nonfatal);
    static const int NC_ERR = 2;
    NcFile NetCDF_File(OUTPUT_FILENAME.c_str(), NcFile::Replace);
    if(!NetCDF_File.is_valid()) {return NC_ERR;}

    if(!(NetCDF_File.add_att("MyString",MyString.c_str()))) {return NC_ERR;}
    if(!(NetCDF_File.add_att("MyInt",MyInt))) {return NC_ERR;}
    if(!(NetCDF_File.add_att("MyFloat",MyFloat))) {return NC_ERR;}

    return 0;
}

int MyStructure::LoadNetCDF(std::string INPUT_FILENAME)
{

    NcError err(NcError::silent_nonfatal);
    static const int NC_ERR = 2;

    NcFile NetCDF_File(INPUT_FILENAME.c_str(), NcFile::ReadOnly);
    if(!NetCDF_File.is_valid()) {return NC_ERR;}

    // ???? This is where I am stuck.
    // How do I read the global attribute from the NetCDF_File ??
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout<< "START OF TEST.\n";

    MyStructure StructureInstance;  // datamembers initialized by constructor
    StructureInstance.SaveNetCDF("TestFile.nc");

    StructureInstance.MyString = "Change string for sake of testing";
    StructureInstance.MyInt = -987; 
    StructureInstance.MyFloat = -9.87;

    StructureInstance.LoadNetCDF("TestFile.nc");    // data members are supposed to be read from file

    std::cout<< "Now the data members of StructureInstance should be TestString, 123, and 1.23\n";
    std::cout<< StructureInstance.MyString << " ; " << StructureInstance.MyInt << " ; " << StructureInstance.MyFloat <<"\n";
    std::cout<< "END OF TEST.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to Rob Latham for the links to a commented description of the NetCDF API (legacy C++). With the information given there I was able to figure it out:

`NcAtt` inherents form `NcTypedComponent` a set of member functions for accessing data stored within a given `NcAtt`: (int n == n-th element)

- `ncbyte as_ncbyte( int n ) const`
- `char as_char( int n ) const`
- `short as_short( int n ) const`
- `int as_int( int n ) const`
- `nclong as_nclong( int n ) const // deprecated`
- `long as_long( int n ) const`
- `float as_float( int n ) const`
- `double as_double( int n ) const`
- `char* as_string( int n ) const`

But still, the constructor for NcAtt is private and the only access point to an existing NcAtt is through the NcFile member function `NcVar* get_var(NcToken name) const` -- which only returns a pointer. Hence the straight forward usage does not work:

`int MyInt = MyNcFile.get_att("MyInt").as_int(0); // DOES NOT COMPILE`

However, dereferencing the pointer returned by `get_att` does the trick.

`int MyInt = (*MyNcFile.get_att("MyInt")).as_int(0); // WORKS`

For sake of completeness I include below the implementation of `MyStructure::LoadNetCDF` for the example code of my original question.

```
int MyStructure::LoadNetCDF(std::string INPUT_FILENAME)
{
    NcError err(NcError::silent_nonfatal);
    static const int NC_ERR = 2;

    NcFile NetCDF_File(INPUT_FILENAME.c_str(), NcFile::ReadOnly);
    if(!NetCDF_File.is_valid()) {return NC_ERR;}

    // NcAtt constructor is private, but one can obtain the pointer to an existing NcAtt
    NcAtt* PointerToMyIntNcAtt = NetCDF_File.get_att("MyInt"); 
    // Now, using the dereferencing operator one has access to the member functions that NcAtt inherents from NcTypedComponent
    if(!(*PointerToMyIntNcAtt).is_valid()) {return NC_ERR;}
    std::cout<< "Is MyInt a valid NcAtt? "<< (*PointerToMyIntNcAtt).is_valid()<<"\n";

    // The concise way of writing the access to NetCDF "global attributes"" of type int/float/string
    MyInt = (*NetCDF_File.get_att("MyInt")).as_int(0);
    MyFloat = (*NetCDF_File.get_att("MyFloat")).as_float(0);
    MyString = (*NetCDF_File.get_att("MyString")).as_string(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to replace `(*NetCDF_File).as_int(0)` with `NetCDF_File->as_int(0)` ?

Comment: This is how to read attributes associated with NcVar I believe -- but it does not work with "global attributes" as the operator is apparently not implemented. When I compile using the "->" operator get the following error: `error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘NcFile’`

Comment: Ooops, that should be: `NetCDF_File.get_att("MyInt")->as_int(0)`...or does that fail?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that this method works as well. So here we have it: two methods work. (1) an "INDIRECTION" using the dereferencing operator (*a.b(); "object pointed to by a has member b"); and (2) "STRUCTURE DEREFERENCE" (a->b(); "member b of object pointed to by a"). I think I just learned a nugget of C/C++. Cool.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clearly spelled out in the C++ users guide: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-cxx/Class-NcAtt.html#Class-NcAtt

"Because attributes are only associated with open netCDF files, there are no public constructors for this class. Use member functions of NcFile and NcVar to get netCDF attributes or add new attributes."

global attributes are attributes on the file (as opposed to variable attributes which are, well, attributes on the variable)

NetCDF_File.num_atts() returns how many global attributes.  The get_att() methods (overloaded in various ways) will get you an attribute.

consult http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-cxx/Class-NcFile.html#Class-NcFile